# Is react-router-dom <Redirect /> not working with syncHistoryWithStore?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm trying to redirect the user to a sign in page when trying to access a page that requires some privileges. Basically, the `/` route requires the user to be logged in so I redirect them to `/signin` if they're not.

Using react-router-redux's syncHistoryWithStore, the redirect just doesn't happen. When I remove it, it works as expected.

Is syncHistoryWithStore incompatible with the latest version of react-router-dom?

Here's a [reproduction](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ks-L6qiLfLHnB-WQWTD). You can uncomment the history line that does not use syncHistoryWithStore and see that it works as expected.

Also embedding the code here on stackoverflow.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    routing: routerReducer
  })
);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);
//const history = createBrowserHistory();

function SignIn(){
  return (
    <div>This is SignIn.</div>
  );
}

function Home(){
  return (
    <div>This is Home.</div>
  );
}

const isLoggedIn = false;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => isLoggedIn ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/signin" />}
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  window.document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: react-router-redux doesn't support react-router v4. See the readme https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Comment: Thanks mate, was so overwhelmed with all the information I did not notice that little sentence. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tharaka pointed out, the readme mentions that react-router v4 is not supported yet.